# Do the structure constants of $\mathfrak{su}(n)$ specify an injective map?

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras, multilinear-algebra

The structure constants of a Lie algebra are determined by $[T^a, T^b] = f^{ab}\,_c T^c$. As a $(2,1)$ tensor, they can however be considered as a linear map from vectors to antisymmetric tensors.

Is this map injective, for the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}(n)$? That is, given $f^{ab}\,_c v^c = A^{ab}$, where $A$ can be obtained from some such $v$, can we solve for $v$? And is there an explicit expression for $v$?

*Edit*: To be even more explicit, my question is whether or not the map $F:v \mapsto A$, where $A^{ab} = \sum_c f^{ab}\,_c v^c$, is injective. Here $v \in \mathbb{R}^{n^2-1}$ is simply some real vector, and $A$ is an antisymmetric tensor acting on the same space. ($a,b,c$ run over $1,\ldots,n^2-1$.)

**Example**: For $\mathfrak{su}(2)$, $f^{ab}\,_c = \epsilon^{ab}\,_c$ is the standard 3D bijection between vectors and antisymmetric tensors, which is invertible. The inverse is given simply by $\epsilon_{ab}\,^c$ up to constants.

(In higher than 3 dimensions, of course, there are more antisymmetric tensors than vectors, which suggests in a hand-waving sense that the map is 'likely' to be injective.)

Comment: Just some thoughts of a physicist: In physics the commutator of two generators of a  (SU(N)) group are considered as the generators of (infintitisimal)translations (i use this in general terms here, it could be translation in time, postion, angle, internal spaces like spin etc. ) from the unit element of the (connected) group to a place near by. In this sense all the operations have to be invertible  (because we also can go back to the unit element) and therefore also the linear map you mention has to be invertible.

Comment: I'm sure what you are asking boils down to either "is the Lie bracket surjective" (yes) or "is the Lie bracket injective" (no, except for $n=2$).  But I can't figure out which because I don't understand how to interpret the structure constants as a map from "vectors" (elements of $\mathfrak{su}(n)$?) to antisymmetric tensors.

Comment: @mt_ I've specified the map $F$ more clearly. Okay, I actually bothered to check $\mathfrak{su}(3)$ at least, where we see the answer is yes, it is injective. For example, using the Gell-Mann basis, the value of $A^{12}$ tells you the value of $v^3$, $A^{13}$ the value of $v^2$, and so on.

Comment: At the top of the question, $f^{ab} {_c T ^c}$ was a linear combination of $T^r$s -- a vector again.  In your third para, $f^{ab} {_cv^c}$ no longer has the same type as $v$, in fact it's an antisymmetric tensor. I'm not saying this is wrong, but it doesn't make sense to me and you need someone who understands this notation to help.

Comment: @mt_ I see your confusion; you are confused about what the right analogy between the two expressions is. Notice that $f^{ab}\,_c v^c$ is (for each $a,b$) a real number, which is a linear combination of the real numbers $v^c$. This is exactly as in the first paragraph, where $f^{ab}\,_c T^c$ is (for each $a,b$) a matrix, which is a linear combination of the matrices $T^c$. Be careful about the fact that $[T^a, T^b]_{ij}$ has two sets of indices.